# Trying to reduce NAIP resolution from 1m GSD to 5m GSD using reduceResolution

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, naip

I'm trying to reduce the resolution of a NAIP mosaic from 1m GSD to 5m GSD. I get the following error:

**Image.reduceResolution: The input to reduceResolution does not have a valid default projection. Use setDefaultProjection() first.**

I tried the following, based on previous answers to a similar question at [reduceResolution failes in GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366216)
, plus the [GEE developers entry on the subject](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/resample). Here's what I tried:

Attempt 1:

```
    var projection = ee.Image(naip.first()).projection();

    image.reproject(projection);

    var reduced = image.reduceResolution({
                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                bestEffort: true,
                maxPixels: 25
    });
```

Attempt 2:

```
    var projection = ee.Image(naip.first()).projection();
    print(projection, 'NAIP Projection');

    image.setDefaultProjection(projection);

    var reduced = image.reduceResolution({
                reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                bestEffort: true,
                maxPixels: 25
    });
```

I also tried some random crs's, to see whether 'reprojecting' into the same coordinate system may have been the answer. No dice.

Here's the [link to the code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/775f8a0b4646625a3623897563cf096d) plus links to the [AOI asset](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/pluharp/fishlake/TimberAOI) and [Mask asset](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/pluharp/fishlake/TimberMask).

Answer (score 1):

You simply failed to capture the results from `setDefaultProjection`.

```
image = image.setDefaultProjection(projection);
```

That said, this operation is probably completely unnecessary. Most of the time, you don't need to reproject or run reduceResolution to downsample; the default downsampling pyramid is going to produce almost identical results.

In this case, just specifying a final projection (like in an Export), you'd get nearest-neighbor sampling from the 16m level of the [image pyramid](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale#image-pyramids).